# How to get node count between table element using htmlagilitypack in c#?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

From below code I want to get node count (which contains class `name`) within particular table element Using HTML Agility Pack c#.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class = "Name">Ram</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Raj</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There is nothing between one node.

Comment: to find node count which contain name class within the table

Comment: The count of what? Of tables or nodes contained in them? All the nodes `tbody`, `tr`, `td`, ... or only rows `tr`? It is not clear what you are asking for. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Something like this: `DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='Name']").Count`? Would need to check there are nodes with a `class="Name"` before doing a `.Count`.

Comment: And for only elements within a table: `"//table//*[@class='Name']"`

Comment: Thanks, its works for particular table "//table[1]//*[@class='Name']"